# realized/unrealized PnL with multiplier

Tags: pnl

Look at this trade:

```
Sequence Side Quantity   @ Price
1.       Buy    1000     @ 1000
2.       Sell   1000     @ 1250
```

The calculation of the realized PnL:

**version 1:**

```
realizedPnL = (1000-1250)*1000 = 25000$
```

But looking at other PnL-formulas, for example:

- https://www.bitmex.com/app/pnlGuide
- https://support.bitforex.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029616532-How-to-calculate-the-unrealized-and-realized-profits-and-loss-PNL-

they use:

**version 2:**

```
realizedPnL = (1/1000-1/1250)*1000 = 0,2$
```

by the formula:

```
Realized PNL  = quantity * multiplier * (1 / Entry Price - 1 / Exit Price)
```

or

**I do not understand the "1/x"-part and the "multiplier"-part**:

1. When and why should I take version 2 instead of version 1?
2. Which version is correct?
3. Has the "1/x" something to do with leverage? Or has the "multiplier" something to do with leverage? For example, if I trade Forex or CFD with a "leverage=1", then "contract multiplier=1". Or do I mix something up?

Comment: It can get a bit confusing when 2 currencies are involved. Here they are trying to compute the profit in XBT, but they have as inputs the XBTUSD price which is in dollars (the rightmost three letters). So they take the inverse price (USDXBT) for their calculation. That is the justification for the $1/x$.

Comment: "Multiplier" is common in futures markets, if you trade in Soybean contracts for example then the Multiplier is simply how many bushels of soybeans make up 1 contract (5000 in this case). It is for convenience in trading, a single bushel is too small a quantity for commercial trading so they trade 5000 at  time.

Comment: For example: I `buy 1 Bitcoin for 10.000$ (BTCUSD)` and `sell 1 Bitcoin for 11.000$ (BTCUSD)`then my realizedPnL is `+1000$ (profit)`. If I want to **express this PnL in BTC**, I must use the formula: `quantity * multiplier * (multiplier / sellPrice$ - multiplier / buyPrice$) = 10000*1*(1/11000 - 1/10000) = -0,0909 (loss)`. Am I right with this calculation? I guess not because PnL in BTC shows a loss, while PnL in $ shows a profit.

Comment: oops! i made a mistake. the signs have to be switched. so it has to be 10000*(1/10000-1/11000). The formula you have in your question is correct. The reason the signs switch is that when you *receive* XBT you *pay out* USD and vice versa. I said I find it easy to get confused and I was right ;)

Comment: @noob2 ok thanks! Now I understand. Please improve my answer if I miss some points.

Comment: @noob2 one question about leveraging and PnL: At first, leveraging **has nothing to do** with the **contract multiplier** discussed here. So I created a new issue: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/53520/realized-unrealized-pnl-with-leverage

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the following confusing formula:

```
PNL  = quantity * multiplier * (1 / Entry Price - 1 / Exit Price)
```

For **all asset classes** the following formula is sufficient:

```
 PNL  = quantity * (ExitPrice - EntryPrice)
```

The "multiplier" is only used when converting from one bucket (e.g. currency) to another. Looking at the following example:

```
Sequence Side Quantity    @ Price in $
1.       Buy    1 BTC     @ 10000
2.       Sell   1 BTC     @ 11000
```

We have

```
PnL = (11000-10000)*1 = +1000$ (profit)
```

in percentage:

```
PnL = (11000/10000) = +0,1% (profit)
```

If I want to express the PnL in BTC instead of $, then I can do the following:

```
PnL = 1/1+0,1 = +0,909BTC
```

The "`1/x`" is fixed and **independent of any multiplier**. 1 represents 100%. That`s all.