# realized/unrealized PnL with leverage

Tags: pnl

Look at this trade:

```
Sequence Side Quantity   @ Price
1.       Buy    10       @ 1,0  (with leverage of 50)
2.       Sell   10       @ 1,2  (inherits the leverage of 50?)
```

Imagine that this trade is a CFD or a forex with USDEUR. I use a leverage of 50 for buy. How should I include this leverage within my PnL calculations?

Is this the right formula:

```
PnL  = quantity * (ExitPrice * exitLeverage - EntryPrice * entryLeverage)
```

**Question:**

Do I need to multiply the entry or exit prices by the leverage at all, or does the broker already returns the  trades with the "leveraged prices"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PnL = Profit - Funding Costs

PnL = (Exit - Entry) - (50 * Capital - Capital) * Funding Rate

% Gain = PnL / Capital

Capital is how much you are investing (inclusive of margin).  Your funding costs is 49 * Capital as that is how much you are borrowing to get to 50x leverage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is right.

You could also do:
Pnl = (Exit - Entry) * Leverage 
To save yourself multiplying by leverage twice.

There are also costs associated with putting trades on/off so these should be taken into consideration.

Comment: The formula seems wrong. The leverage of exit and entry can be different, because when using (for example, FIFO), then I must sum up all trades from the entry side which can have different leverages and the trades from the exit side (which also can have different leverages).